# Android INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI

Tags: android, apk

I just started getting the following error when I attempt to install an Android application to a device through Eclipse:

```
Installation failed due to invalid URI!
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!
```

I've also tried installing both the APK in the `bin` folder and a signed APK through adb. When I do this, I get an `INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI` error.

I haven't changed anything about my setup, and it used to work without a problem.

Any ideas? Thanks!

LogCat output:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(32345): CheckJNI is OFF
D/dalvikvm(32345): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/com.orange.authentication.simcard.jar'
D/AndroidRuntime(32345): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
V/Performance(32111): >>com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService@40d944a8 onCreate
V/Performance(32111): <<com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService@40d944a8 onCreate, 3ms
V/Performance(32111): >>com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService@40d944a8 onBind
V/Performance(32111): <<com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService@40d944a8 onBind, 1ms
W/asset   (32111): Asset path /data/local/tmp/CS2110Project.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=0).
W/DefContainer(32111): Failed to parse package
W/ActivityManager(  744): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/CS2110Project.apk
D/dalvikvm(  744): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1196K, 36% free 20088K/31267K, paused 10ms+14ms
D/AndroidRuntime(32345): Shutting down VM
I/AndroidRuntime(32345): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
D/dalvikvm(32345): GC_CONCURRENT freed 135K, 72% free 578K/2048K, paused 1ms+1ms
D/dalvikvm(32345): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
```

Comment: Another possible cause for this issue is due to unsupported characters in project name (for example æ ø å or similar)

Comment: Flagging "too broad" as there are clearly easily half a dozen or more possible root causes as evidenced by the wide variety of unrelated answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turned out to be a ROM issue. I reflashed to a newer ROM and everything works just fine now. Seems to be a fairly common problem actually.

Comment: http://forum.aokp.co/topic/60-cant-install-apk-from-eclipse-or-adb/ was the problem, you need to change the permissions on the /data/local directory!, got Milestone 5 working!!! woot

Comment: Note 2 on stock rom but rooted is giving me this Installation failed due to invalid APK file!

Answer (score 16):

For ME, it wanted the full path.

- pm install joe.apk failed.
- pm install ./joe.apk failed.
- chmod'ed everything, still failed.
- **pm install /data/joe.apk worked.**

Comment: There are a host of reasons that can cause the behavior in the OP.   I was using the terminal emulator on the device and I also had to provide a full path or I got "invalid uri" from pm.  It's a shame that the error message in the system log isn't more helpful.  Thanks FrankRizzo, this had been driving me crazy because I was having a different experience when using the adb shell.  Which shell you're using matters!

Comment: it happened in real device too. as per the answer installing from /data/local/tmp worked

Answer (score 10):

Just for the record:

For me it turned out to be an **umlaut (ä,ü,ö)** Problem in the Project name.

I did the following to solve it:

1. **`Refactor`** -> **`Rename`** (replaced the umlauts)
2. did a **`Project`** -> **`Clean`**

Hope this saves some time to others… took me quite a while.

Answer (score 5):

For me, I rooted my device and every time i turn the phone on it re-updates android. With that in mind, I had to reset the chmod 777 to the local directory. So this is more of a reminder to check your permissions then an answer but it may help someone.

Comment: Setting the local directory permissions to 777 got rid of the  INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI for me, but then I got INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK until I also set the apk permissions to 777.

Comment: Setting the apk permissions to 777 solved the issue for me

Answer (score 5):

not have accents or unusual characters. I had the accent and the name of the apk generated an error when going to install, remove the tick and it worked

Answer (score 3):

Do you have your device set up for debugging? If you haven't already you might need to go to Settings -> Applications and allow Unknown Sources.
If that doesn't help: what's in your logcat output?

Comment: Debugging is on. I put in the logcat output above.

Comment: Solved my issue using your method.

Comment: In Android 5, it is in Security settings

Answer (score 1):

on my device is because of minSdkVersion is below than you device android sdk

Answer (score 1):

When you do an "adb install -r some_app.apk", it gives the pkg as "/data/local/tmp/some_app.apk Success". If you give the option -r in a wrong place it takes the pkg as -r and gives the above error. Hence after chmod of data, local & tmp dir, check if it is able to parse pkg properly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but it might still help someone.

I ran into this same problem when installing a list of apps from a text file, so I can install them programmatically.  I created the file in Windows then pushed it to tablet with ADB.  Windows puts a carriage return and line feed at the end of every line.

**Make sure that there is only a line feed (make the file on *nix box or remove CR from Windows file) at the end of every line**

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a console issue. I used the "terminal" on the Mac and it didn't work. 
When I used the build in console of AndroidStudio it worked though.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run

`readlink -f PATH_of_APK`

or

`readlink -e PATH_of_APK`

first to get the legal path for pm command.

E.g. on my termux:

```
$readlink -f /data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/downloads/

/storage/emulated/0/Download
```

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting my device solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was giving the wrong command. I thought I needed to specify the device, so I was doing:

```
adb install -s X0Y1ZZ23456789XY "G:\com.my.apk"
```

when I should've been doing:

```
adb install "G:\com.my.apk"
```

The thing is: the apk was transferring fine, it just failed at the end like this. Like others have said, it's a shame you don't get better errors from this tool. :-|