# Installation failed due to an invalid URI

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
[2013-07-21 11:14:01 - AndroidTrial] Installation failed due to invalid URI!
[2013-07-21 11:14:01 - AndroidTrial] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-07-21 11:14:02 - AndroidTrial] Launch canceled!
```

This is what I get when I try to run a trial project. There is no output in the logcat.
I looked at other answer on SO for similar problems and they say that it can be because of accented characters. I do not have any of those.

Here is what my simple code looks like:

```
public class HaikuDisplay extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void onTrialButtonClicked(View view){
        TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

And here is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HaikuDisplay" >
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/topBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/love_button_text"
        android:onClick="onTrialButtonClicked"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/topBtn"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" 
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**how do I solve that?**

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10182645/2398886

Comment: @Tarsem I am on Eclipse

Comment: did you tried by cleaning project ?

Comment: Are you installing the app on your device or emulator?

Comment: @vikram Emulator. Even Eclipse generated blank projects give the same error. Previously, they ran fine.

Comment: You should restart eclipse > create a new avd > try running the project. And if you can, run the app on a device to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This error can point to so many different things, and there is many different fixes. To sum those I've gathered:

1. **Problems with Eclipse:** Clean project, rebuild project, restart
   eclipse.
2. **Invalid characters:** Remove any special characters in Eclipse project name.
   Use only [a-z] and [0-9] not even [ ] (whitespace)
3. **Error in included jar:** Try without jar and see if it runs, if does fix somehow.
4. **Errors in manifest package setup:** Right click in eclipse on project -> `Android tools` -> `Rename application package` (rename to something similar, you can always rename back).
5. **Problems with device:** Remove app from device and try re install.
6. **Rom issue:** If you use custom ROM try to reflash to a new ROM.
7. **Debugging not enabled:** On phone go to `Settings` -> `Applications` -> `Allow unknown sources/enable debugging` (this path can vary for different devices)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the Android project name as it contained German umlauts: **äüö..**. I refactored the name and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I had changed the name of my app the strings.xml file:

```
<string name="app_name">My App</string>
```

Removing the app and reinstalling it solved the problem.