# android error while installing .apk on emulator

Tags: android

I'm pretty much new to android development.I made a very basic program and when I try to run it on the emulator,the following error is encountered:

`[2014-07-13 15:54:26 - AndroidLove] Starting activity com.example.androidlove.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-07-13 15:54:32 - AndroidLove] Installation failed due to invalid URI!
[2014-07-13 15:54:32 - AndroidLove] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-07-13 15:54:32 - AndroidLove] Launch cancelled!`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: clear the project and run it or restart your emulator, if your running on a real device just unplug and plug cable to device and run your project.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons failing the apk installation on your emulator.

Have a look here :

[Installation failed due to an invalid URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769496/installation-failed-due-to-an-invalid-uri)